# How can I prevent users viewing the contents of a folder, but allow them access to specific files

Tags: active-directory

We use windows server 2003 and I wanting to know how I can limit users access to certain folders. I have a directory that I want user to be able to read the documents if I provide them with a direct shortcut, but I do not want to allow them to review all the folder content only read the files I provide with a direct link to.?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you need to point users to a directory they can't view the contents of?

Comment: I don't think the why is particularly important, but I've come across this need before where I had a folder that stored all the organisations contracts. It is a legitimate question.  It doesn't deserve down votes.

Comment: @dunxd Setting up ABE and Permissions is the "correct" way of doing this. The downvotes are almost certainly due to the preconceived notions and presumption of solution without stating the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to set the permissions on the files to be what you want them to be.

I would set them up as follows:

1. Create a folder.  Set the permissions to "Authenticated Users-List Folder Contents-This Level Only" and you "Full control-This folder, files, and subfolders"
2. Add files to the folder.  By default you will have access to the files, and everyone else will just be able to see the names of the files.
3. When you want to share a file with someone, add explicit permissions to the specific files that allow them read access to the file.  Then send them a link to the file.

Let me clarify... this not what I would do probably... but this is how I would do it if I needed to do what you have asked to do.